# Open an Image from Computer Using PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

Below is my code, every time I run it Windows Photo Viewer opens but all it says is loading. Why will my image not load?

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

im =Image.open("Penguins.jpg")
im.show()
```

Comment: I have my working directory changed and my code and image are in the same folder.

Comment: try a `print(im)` see what the result is.